# Adding selectmenu to collapsible

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Running JQM 1.4.5

Not sure if this is even possible. Trying to add a selectmenu to a collapsible header. I've tried all kinds of things but this is as close as I've gotten:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed="true" id="my_id">
<h4>Butterflies
  <span class="select" style="float: right;" onclick="run(this);"><select name="select_name" id="select_id" data-native-menu="false"><option value="1">The 1st Option</option><option value="2">The 2nd Option</option></select></div>
  </span>
</h4>
<p>Read about Butterflies</p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$.widget('mobile.collapsible', $.mobile.collapsible, {
     _handleExpandCollapse: function (isCollapse) {
        if (this._trigger('before' + (isCollapse ? 'collapse' : 'expand'))) {
            this._superApply(arguments);
        }
    }
});

function run(object) {
    $('.ui-collapsible').on('collapsiblebeforeexpand', function (event, ui) {
        (this).child().selectmenu("open");
    });
}
```

So the behavior of this code in Google Chrome is as follows:

1) Click on the collapsible header bar, it opens and closes as expected
2) Click on selectmenu, it opens as expected and I can select an option

BUT

Clicking on the collapsible header bar no longer works. I can no longer open any collapsible headers. The headers turn blue when clicked but nothing happens.

Comment: Can I ask what purpose will this serve? It is an odd UI for users. The UIs of JQM and Bootstrap are familiar to users, which make them effective. Something like this may confuse. Do you hope to change the content of the collapsible based on what the user selects? You could disable the collapsible and trigger it manually when a selection is made

Comment: The purpose is:

1) To minimize the number of clicks. I don't want the user to have to open the collapsed set to access the button.

2) Make sure the button is visible. I don't want to put it under the collapsed header because when it's open, the select menu will be below the screen. I don't think it's a good idea to have the select menu moving around on the user.

3) Save space.

Comment: Oh, and the other problem I'm having is that this selectmenu is floated to the right to make it small because I don't want it to take up the width of the whole screen. When floated right and below the coallapsible header, I have a similar problem in that clicking on it activate the collapsible header directly beneath the selectmenu.